# Visual Studio debug app like eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

Is it possible to run/debug multiple projects in visual studio (2010) just like you would do it
in eclipse.

There you can have as many mains running (talking about eclipse for java here) as possible and you could see the nicely.
Furthermore, why does Visual Studio lock all files, even the files independent from current running project?

What i would like to do is simple (seems impossible in visual studio): run a web applications and then debug a automated WatiN test that would do a specific operation on the app such that i can see step by step the automation tool in action, though developing/validating my test.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run multiple projects in debug mode. Just right-click on project and the `Debug->Start New Instance`

Comment: yes, but it will still lock the other files, that tests files that i'm interested in editing and debuggin later.